# Mean value by stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Let $u^{(0)}:=v \in R^d$ and $u^{(k+1)}:=Hu^{(k)}, H \in R^{d,d}$   being a symmetrical matrix with nonnegative coefficients such that the sum of its row elements is 1 for each row. I need to prove the following: $$\, \frac{1}{d}\sum_{j=1}^{d}u_j^{(k)}=\frac{1}{d}\sum_{j=1}^{d}v_j$$

It is clear that $u^{(k+1)}=H^{k+1}u^{(0)}.$ I am wondering if a property of symmetrical matrix should be used. While $H$ is a symmetrical matrix, $H^{k+1}$ must not be one. Since the elements of each row of $H$ sum up to 1,the convex combination of the components of the vector $v$ gives a value situated between the smallest and largest component of $v$. I do not know how to proceed. Can somebody provide some hint or prove the statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make the calculations:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^d u_i^{(k)} = & \sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^d H_{ij} u_j^{(k-1)}=\sum_{j=1}^d \sum_{i=1}^d H_{ij} u_j^{(k-1)} = \sum_{j=1}^d u_j^{(k-1)}\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^d H_{ij}}_{=1} = \sum_{j=1}^d u_j^{(k-1)}
\end{align*}

if the sum of the elements is kept from one iteration to the next, it will always be equal to the sum of the elements in $u^{(0)}=v$. I don't see the need for requiring that $H$ has positive elements. It is also not necessary that $H$ is symmetric, it is only necessary that the sum of the elements is each column is 1.